# Checking if image is fully loaded or NOT

Tags: javascript, jquery

I found this method below and it works fine in order to check if an image is fully loaded:

```
var myimg = new Image();
myimg.onload = function(){
alert("The image is now loaded");
}
myimg.src = "image url";
```

My question is:

How can I do an `alert("The image couldn't be loaded")` if, for some reason, the image couldn't be loaded or found (e.g., if the image URL is broken or even the image no longer exists from the provided image url)? Is there a way to solve this?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`image nodes` also allow for a *DOM Level 1* `onerror` event handler.

```
myimg.onerror = function() {
};
```

If anything fails on loading or while loading an image, that handler will get executed. In addition to that, its not a bad idea at all to also check for the dimenions within the *onload event*

```
myimg.onload = function() {
    if( this.height && this.width ) {
    } else {
        // you might want to catch this case here too
    }
}
```